# How to display list of product category and subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I configured the following products categories structure :

1. Category 1

   - Subcategory 1
   - Subcategory 2
   - Subcategory 3
2. Category 2

   - Subcategory 4
   - Subcategory 5
   - Subcategory 6

and I would like to display a list of category/subcategories based on this behavior :

- When on Category 1: Display All Child Subcategories (1 + 2 + 3)
- When on SubCategory 1: Display Category 1 + Subcategories 2 and 3
- When on SubCategory 2: Display Category 1 + Subcategories 1 and 3
- When on Category 2: Display All Child Subcategories (4 + 5 + 6)
- When on SubCategory 4: Display Category 2 + Subcategories 5 and 6
- etc

I already tried lots of different codes and got some results, but none of them are excluding the current subcategory when on it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _Show us_, what you actually tried, instead of just telling us, _that_ you tried “something”.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would recommend reading  [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  on how to write a quality question. This helps for better understanding for the contributers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this two posts : [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/361045/get-child-product-categories-from-parent-product-category-in-woocommerce) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794522/get-parent-category-terms-and-use-slug-to-create-menu-wordpress) I managed to get the result ! I also added a code to display parent category when i'm on a subcategory.

```
    $current_category = get_queried_object();

    /** PARENTS **/
    /** Get Category ID of current page **/
    $current_category_id = $current_category->term_id;

    /** Get Array of Category Parents **/
    $parent_cat = get_ancestors($current_category_id, 'product_cat');
       
    /** Get infos of first Parent **/
    $parent_cat_term = get_term( $parent_cat[0], 'product_cat' );
    $parent_cat_name = $parent_cat_term->name;
    $parent_cat_id = $parent_cat_term->term_id;
    
    /** CHILD **/ 
    if ( $current_category->parent != 0 ) {
        $child_cat_ids = get_term_children( $current_category->parent, 'product_cat' );
    
    /** DISPLAY PARENT **/ 
            if (!empty($parent_cat_id))/** Avoid error when no parent **/{
            echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $parent_cat_id, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $parent_cat_name . '</a>';           
            }
    /** DISPLAY CHILDS **/ 
            foreach ( $child_cat_ids as $child_cat_id ) {
                if( $child_cat_id != $current_category->term_id ) {
                    $child_cat_term = get_term_by( 'id', $child_cat_id, 'product_cat' );
                    echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $child_cat_id, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $child_cat_term->name . '</a>';
                }
            }
    }
```